# Initializing a variable initialized from IBoutlet variables for a view controller?

Tags: swift

I am trying to initialize the variable deckEditorModel using termAndDefTable and copyNPasteTable as inputs. I don't want deckEditorModel to be an optional variable as a know that I would not be able to use that tactic in C. I tried putting deckEditorModel in the init methods for the view controller but it seems that the  required `termNDefTable: termAndDefTable, otherTable: OtherTable` are not available to use as imputs during the init as they are IBOutlets. How would someone go about this

```
import Cocoa

class DeckEditorViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var importToolsView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var termAndDefTable: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var otherTable: NSTableView!

    var deckEditorModel:DeckEditorModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        deckEditorModel = DeckEditorModel(termNDefTable: termAndDefTable, otherTable: otherTable)
    }
```

I tried adding it to the viewDidLoad but apparently that is to late to define deckEditorModel. The below error dissappears when deckEditorModel is an optional

[image: The below error dissappears when deckEditorModel is an optional]

Comment: Why avoid Swift constructs simply because they're not available in C? Are you planning to port your code to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize the variable lazily

```
lazy var deckEditorModel : DeckEditorModel = {
   return DeckEditorModel(termNDefTable: self.termAndDefTable, otherTable: self.otherTable)
}()
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. I thought lazy var would work. Didn't have much experience with lazy vars through.

Comment: It's a pretty convenient way to avoid optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
deckEditorModel = DeckEditorModel(termNDefTable: termAndDefTable, otherTable: otherTable)
```

In viewDidLoad, then the outlets will have been set.